# Cambiar ruta de php en Composer

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer

Buenos días colegas!!!

Me estoy iniciando en Laravel y luego de algunos inconvenientes con MAMP preferí no trabajar con el y me fuí por XAMPP.

Durante la instalación de Composer le dí la ruta del php de MAMP y quisiera redirigir al php de XAMPP.

Primero, como puedo ver si en verdad la ruta de php en Composer es la que estoy comentando?

Y segundo, como puedo cambiar esa ruta de php a otra que yo desee?

Comment: Como dices que querías usar MAMP, ¿tu sistema operativo es macOS?

Comment: Disculpa, no especifique que estoy en Windows 7

Comment: Se estás en Windows mi recomendación es que utilices Laragon que te va a facilitar la vida sobre todo cuando trabajas con múltiples proyectos, además ya proporciona composer, npm y otros por defecto en su consola entre otras utilidades. También cambiar de una versión a otra de PHP es fácil, así como cambiar motor de base de datos o entre Apache y nginx.  https://laragon.org/

Answer (score 0):

Según [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193976/323149) respuesta en inglés:

1. Busca "variables de entorno" con Cortana (si sabes dónde están, creo que no hace falta que se lo pidas a Cortana...)
2. Pulsa el botón de variables de entorno
3. En variables de sistema, selecciona `PATH` y edítala
4. En tu caso, deberías ver alguna entrada que tenga que ver con MAMP (c:\MAMP\bin o similar)
5. Cambia dicha ruta por la que corresponda con el PHP del XAMPP

Para comprobar que ha funcionado, abre una nueva consola de comandos (cmd) y escribe `php -v` y comprueba si te imprime en pantalla la versión que coincide con XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Una buena alternativa es que corras con versiones especificas tanto php artisan como composer install o update, siempre apuntando a los directorios de instalacion.

Ejemplo en linux para correr composer install:

/usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/local/bin/composer install

artisan:

/usr/bin/php7.0 artisan {comando}